# Float data is not showing correctly on select menu in mobile view

Tags: php, html, laravel, select

I'm not sure why in the desktop is working, but on the phone, it showed like this `2 hrs` + `2 oz`

[image]

It seems like it loaded the default value `2`. Even if the Chrome simulator showed the wrong `only` the mobile view. It's a `float` in the database.

[image]

see its value inside the db

[image]

---

## Update

```
public function settingsUpdate($id){
    $baby     = Baby::where('uuid',$id)->first();   
    if($baby){

        $baby->name            = Request::get('name','');
        $baby->phone           = Request::get('phone','');
        $baby->email           = Request::get('email','');
        $baby->babyName        = Request::get('babyName','');
        $baby->babyDob         = Request::get('babyDob','').' '.Request::get('babyHob','').':00';
        $baby->adminCode       = Request::get('adminCode','');
        $baby->readOnlyCode    = Request::get('readOnlyCode','');
        $baby->feedingInterval = (float) Request::get('feedingInterval',''); <<<----------  ✨
        $baby->feedingAmount   = (float) Request::get('feedingAmount',''); <<<----------  ✨
        $baby->displayMode     = Request::get('displayMode','');

        $baby->save();

        return Redirect::to('/baby/'.$baby->uuid.'?code='.$baby->adminCode);

    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

---

## HTML/View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="feedingInterval"><h5>Feeding Interval <small class="helpText">(hours)</small></h5></label>

        <select class="form-control" id="feedingInterval" name="feedingInterval">
            <option value="2">2 hrs </option>
            <option value="2.5">2.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="3">3 hrs </option>
            <option value="3.5">3.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="4">4 hrs </option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="5">5 hrs </option>
            <option value="5.5">5.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="6">6 hrs </option>
        </select>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="feedingAmount"><h5>Feeding Amount <small class="helpText">(ounces)</small></h5></label>

        <select class="form-control" id="feedingAmount" name="feedingAmount">
            <option value="2">2 oz </option>
            <option value="2.5">2.5 oz </option>
            <option value="3">3 oz </option>
            <option value="3.5">3.5 oz </option>
            <option value="4">4 oz </option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5 oz </option>
            <option value="5">5 oz </option>
            <option value="5.5">5.5 oz </option>
            <option value="6">6 oz </option>
        </select>
        
    </div>



</div>
```

---

## GET

```
    $('#feedingInterval').val(`{{$baby->feedingInterval}}`.toString());
    $('#feedingAmount').val(`{{$baby->feedingAmount}}`.toString());
```

Comment: Show your code sample.

Comment: @shahidiqbal I added more codes now.

Comment: @shahidiqbal Anything else you would like to see ? I'm more than happy to provide.

Comment: Can you share complete code of this component? I want to go through the code.

Comment: Both desktop and mobile

Comment: @shahidiqbal Desktop & Mobile using the same code, to `update()` & `get()`, I've tried set the menu base on my GET via JS

Comment: @shahidiqbal Somehow, iOS display select menu very weirdly : https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/select-css.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231613/discussion-between-shahidiqbal-and-cyb3rz).